# Is it possible to create custom WorkItem states on TFS

Tags: team-foundation-server

Is there a way to change Work Item state names, or add new ones if we are running TFS on premises? For example, scrum story has states like committed, done, approved, etc. Is it possible to add new states or rename existing ones?

This resource explains how to do it on VSTS:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav but it is not clear whether this functionality exists for TFS on premises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page describe the new model to manage Processes and Work Item Types. On premise you should use the older "Hosted XML" model and you can start reading from the [Add or modify a work item type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/add-modify-wit?view=tfs-2018) page.

Keep in mind that Hosted XML is not recommended for VSTS. This means that you should try to minimize your changes and document them thoroughly in case you plan a future migration from TFS on-prem to VSTS.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Do you know what will happen to existing work items if work item state name is changed? For example, I had tasks in state "To Do". What will happen to them if I change name of state of work item "Task" from "To Do" to "To Be Done"?